# Finding zero of nonlinear simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I'm trying to find the zero of nonlinear simultaneous equations defined in `myfun1` and `myfun2`:

```
myfun1[x0_, a_] :=
 Module[{x, y, u, z},

  x = x0[[1]];
  y = x0[[2]];
  u = x + y;

  z = a*u^2 - 3
  ]

myfun2[x0_, a_] :=
 Module[{x, y, u, z},

  x = x0[[1]];
  y = x0[[2]];
  u = x - y;

  z = a*u^2 + 1.3*Sqrt[u]
  ]

x0 = {3, 4};   (* initial guess *)
a = 2.1;       (* constant parameter *)

NSolve[{myfun1[x0, a] == 0, myfun2[x0, a] == 0}, x0, Reals]
```

I get an error message

```
NSolve::ivar: 3 is not a valid variable.
```

with output

```
NSolve[{False, False}, {3, 4}, Reals]
```

I'm new to Mathematica, so I'm not exactly sure how the syntax works. Can you please help?

Comment: I don't see any issue with syntax. A simple diagnostic test will show that the functions are not working as expected. `In[565]:= myfun1[x0, a]

Out[565]= 99.9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `x0` defined, so you can't use it as a variable.  Try this,

```
NSolve[{myfun1[{xa, xb}, a] == 0, 
  myfun2[{xa, xb}, a] == 0}, {xa, xb}, Reals]
(* {{xa -> -0.597614, xb -> -0.597614}, {xa -> 0.597614, 
  xb -> 0.597614}} *)
```

This gives the answer in the form of replacement rules.  You can test your answer like this,

```
{myfun1[{xa, xb}, a], myfun2[{xa, xb}, a]} /. %
(* {{-2.57572*10^-14, 
  7.48062*10^-30 + 5.64772*10^-8 I}, {-6.12843*10^-14, 5.12522*10^-8}} *)
```

You find that to within 10^-8, this satisfies your equations.

### Edit

If you need to find the answer near a guess value, then `FindRoot` is the way to go,

```
FindRoot[{myfun1[{xa, xb}, a] == 0, 
  myfun2[{xa, xb}, a] == 0}, {{xa, 4}, {xb, 3}}]
(* {xa -> 0.597614 + 2.54413*10^-23 I, 
 xb -> 0.597614 + 2.54414*10^-23 I} *)
```

Bear in mind that you cannot restrict the domain to `Reals` using `FindRoot` like you can with `NSolve`, but in this case it found the right answers anyway.

Comment: Thanks @JasonB, but what if I want to make an initial guess for `x0`? I want to solve a similar but much more complicated equation analytically (this is just a MWE). I know my simultaneous equations must have a solution around certain `xa` and `xb` values, so is there a way to incorporate this into the code?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata, then you need `FindRoot`, see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out a more direct way to formulate your problem that takes advantage of *Mathematica*'s argument destructing capabilities.

```
myfun1[{x_, y_}, a_] := a (x + y)^2 - 3.
myfun2[{x_, y_}, a_] := a (x - y)^2 + 1.3 Sqrt[x - y]

sol = 
  With[{a = 2.1},
    NSolve[{myfun1[{x, y}, a] == 0, myfun2[{x, y}, a] == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]]
```

> `{{x -> -0.597614, y -> -0.597614}, {x -> 0.597614, y -> 0.597614}}`

As Jason B points out in his answer, it is good to verify solutions. In this case I will give a visual verification by plotting the two surfaces and placing markers at the positions of the roots given by `sol`. I do so because I think it makes a rather attractive 3d plot.

```
With[{a = 2.1},
  Show[
    Plot3D[{myfun1[{x, y}, a], myfun2[{x, y}, a]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
    Graphics3D[{Red, Ellipsoid[{x, y, 0.}, .05 {1, 1, 7.5}] /. sol}],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]
```

[image: solns]